# Cannot specify link libraries for target "cv_bridge-utest" ROS compilation error

Tags: opencv, ros

I'm trying to compile a ROS project involving `catkin_make`. The project involves - amongst others- a tool to convert opencv matrices to ros matrices called `cv_bridge`. However, when trying to compile my `catkin_ws` I'm getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at cv_bridge/test/CMakeLists.txt:7 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "cv_bridge-utest" which is not
  built by this project.
```

Does anyone know this error? I'm quite new to ROS, so I'm not sure how to tell ROS to compile the entire `catkin_ws/src` directory. In that latter folder all necessary folders should be present. There is also `catkin_ws/src/cv_bridge` but maybe it tries to compile the folder in the wrong order ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have written in your CMakeLists. Supposing that the error lays there, you can use a CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(your_project)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  cv_bridge
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

###########
## Build ##
###########

catkin_package()

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  include
)


add_executable(executable src/your_file.cpp)
target_link_libraries(executable ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

In your package.xml add these lines:

```
  <build_depend>opencv2</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>

  <run_depend>opencv2</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_bridge</run_depend>
```

To compile the folder you just have to go to your catkin directory and type: catkin_make
If you have built your workspace in the right way, it should compile without error.

Comment: Actually I guess my cv_bridge package might be corrupted. I need to use OpenCV 3.0.0 which I compiled locally and which is different from my system OpenCV. So I tried to modify all `CMakeLists.txt` such that they point to the locally installed opencv. However I guess cv_bridge is still seeing the global opencv version (2.4.8 --> default version of Ubuntu 14.04). Can I reinstall cv_bridge and point it to my local version of opencv?

Comment: I installed cv_bridge typing this in my terminal:

`cd ~/Downloads/ ;
wget https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/2.4.12.zip -O     opencv_2.4.12.zip ;
unzip opencv_2.4.12.zip ;
mv opencv-2.4.12 ~/workspace/opencv ;

cd ~/workspace/opencv ;
mkdir build ;
cd build ;
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF .. ;
make -j 8 ;
sudo make install;`

Comment: Seems like my ROS installation is broke and I'm unable to recover it. `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages` ... However things are compiling in a virtual machine. Thanks anyway